# adding columns to the appropriate rows by matching the first two columns

Tags: awk, grep

I want to use the first two columns of each file to add additional columns from fil2, file3, and file4 to file1 at the appropriate rows (where the first two columns match). File2 has three columns to add to file1, but all other files have just one column to add, the last one.

The entries `NW_456 44` and `NW_987 75` are not annotated in file3 and thus missing. I would like to keep this empty in the output file for that particular column (without it actually saying 'empty').

Example:

file1

```
NW_1234 23
NW_1234 29
NW_1234 778
NW_456 44
NW_987 75
NW_987 98
NW_5000 105
NW_5500 37
NW_5500 900
```

file2

```
NW_1234 23  C   0:0:32:0:0:0    42:0:0:0:0:0
NW_1234 29  C   0:0:28:0:0:0    0:28:0:0:0:0
NW_1234 778 C   0:54:0:0:0:0    0:0:53:0:0:0
NW_456  44  G   0:0:0:45:0:0    59:0:0:0:0:0
NW_987  75  G   0:0:0:60:0:0    55:0:0:0:0:0
NW_987  98  C   0:0:63:0:0:0    0:42:0:0:0:0
NW_5000 105 G   0:0:71:0:0:0    0:50:0:0:0:0
NW_5500 37  G   0:0:0:54:0:0    55:0:0:0:0:0
NW_5500 900 A   43:0:0:0:0:0    0:0:0:37:0:0
```

file3

```
NW_1234 23  DOCK
NW_1234 29  DOCK
NW_1234 778 DOCK
NW_987  98  TFEC
NW_5000 105 MIN
NW_5500 37  LIPG
NW_5500 900 MYC
```

FILE4

```
NW_1234 23  intron_region
NW_1234 29  intron_region
NW_1234 778 intron_region
NW_456  44  intergenic
NW_987  75  intergenic
NW_987  98  intron_region
NW_5000 105 intron_region
NW_5500 37  intron_region
NW_5500 900 intron_region
```

outputfile

```
NW_1234 23  C   0:0:32:0:0:0    42:0:0:0:0:0 DOCK intron_region
NW_1234 29  C   0:0:28:0:0:0    0:28:0:0:0:0 DOCK intron_region
NW_1234 778 C   0:54:0:0:0:0    0:0:53:0:0:0 DOCK intron_region
NW_456  44  G   0:0:0:45:0:0    59:0:0:0:0:0 (empty) intergenic
NW_987  75  G   0:0:0:60:0:0    55:0:0:0:0:0 (empty) intergenic
NW_987  98  C   0:0:63:0:0:0    0:42:0:0:0:0 TFEC intron_region
NW_5000 105 G   0:0:71:0:0:0    0:50:0:0:0:0 MIN  intron_region
NW_5500 37  G   0:0:0:54:0:0    55:0:0:0:0:0 LIPG intron_region
NW_5500 900 A   43:0:0:0:0:0    0:0:0:37:0:0 MYC  intron_region
```

Similar to this question: [Adding column based on matching of second column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222744/adding-column-based-on-matching-of-second-column)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are your files' delimiters? What exactly do you want to happen for the missing entries? should there be an empty (but delimited) field, or is it acceptable for such cases to have fewer columns? Is `perl` available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tabs as the output field separators this will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t";  }
FNR==1 { fileNr++ }
{
    key = $1 OFS $2
    if (NR == FNR) {
        keys[++numKeys] = key
    }
    else {
        sub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/,"")
        $1 = $1
        vals[key,fileNr] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s", key
        for (fileNr=2; fileNr<ARGC; fileNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, vals[key,fileNr]
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3 file4
NW_1234 23      C       0:0:32:0:0:0    42:0:0:0:0:0    DOCK    intron_region
NW_1234 29      C       0:0:28:0:0:0    0:28:0:0:0:0    DOCK    intron_region
NW_1234 778     C       0:54:0:0:0:0    0:0:53:0:0:0    DOCK    intron_region
NW_456  44      G       0:0:0:45:0:0    59:0:0:0:0:0            intergenic
NW_987  75      G       0:0:0:60:0:0    55:0:0:0:0:0            intergenic
NW_987  98      C       0:0:63:0:0:0    0:42:0:0:0:0    TFEC    intron_region
NW_5000 105     G       0:0:71:0:0:0    0:50:0:0:0:0    MIN     intron_region
NW_5500 37      G       0:0:0:54:0:0    55:0:0:0:0:0    LIPG    intron_region
NW_5500 900     A       43:0:0:0:0:0    0:0:0:37:0:0    MYC     intron_region
```

To have the spaces be blanks instead (far less useful for further tool parsing) just pipe to `column`:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3 file4 | column -s$'\t' -t
NW_1234  23   C  0:0:32:0:0:0  42:0:0:0:0:0  DOCK  intron_region
NW_1234  29   C  0:0:28:0:0:0  0:28:0:0:0:0  DOCK  intron_region
NW_1234  778  C  0:54:0:0:0:0  0:0:53:0:0:0  DOCK  intron_region
NW_456   44   G  0:0:0:45:0:0  59:0:0:0:0:0        intergenic
NW_987   75   G  0:0:0:60:0:0  55:0:0:0:0:0        intergenic
NW_987   98   C  0:0:63:0:0:0  0:42:0:0:0:0  TFEC  intron_region
NW_5000  105  G  0:0:71:0:0:0  0:50:0:0:0:0  MIN   intron_region
NW_5500  37   G  0:0:0:54:0:0  55:0:0:0:0:0  LIPG  intron_region
NW_5500  900  A  43:0:0:0:0:0  0:0:0:37:0:0  MYC   intron_region
```