# add two fields with letters which are coded as colon-separated numbers in fields 4 and 5

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i want to create a 8th and 9th field/column with the appropriate letter coded in as numbers in columns 4 and 5.  The six colon seperated numbers correspond to `A:T:C:G:N:del`

Note: some rows in column 6 and 7 are empty which I fixed by inserting NA with this:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]' '$5 && !$6{ $6="NA" }1' 
awk -F'[[:space:]]' '$6 && !$7{ $7="NA" }1'
```

Then made the file tab-delimited again with `sed -e 's/ /\t/g'`

File.tsv

```
    NW_006532398.1  302035  C   0:0:32:0:0:0    42:0:0:0:0:0    KCND2   intergenic_region
    NW_006532656.1  289636  C   0:0:28:0:0:0    0:28:0:0:0:0    CNTN1   intron_variant
    NW_006532762.1  6396    C   0:54:0:0:0:0    0:0:53:0:0:0    NA  intergenic_region
    NW_006532762.1  25741   C   0:0:62:0:0:0    0:43:0:0:0:0    NA  intergenic_region
    NW_006532762.1  32304   T   0:60:0:0:0:0    0:0:49:0:0:0    NA  intergenic_region
    NW_006532762.1  179065  G   0:0:0:45:0:0    59:0:0:0:0:0    DOCK4   intron_variant
```

Example of output.tsv

```
NW_006532398.1  302035  C   0:0:32:0:0:0    42:0:0:0:0:0    KCND2   intergenic_region   C   A
NW_006532656.1  289636  C   0:0:28:0:0:0    0:28:0:0:0:0    CNTN1   intron_variant  C   T
NW_006532762.1  6396    C   0:54:0:0:0:0    0:0:53:0:0:0     NA   intergenic_region T   C
NW_006532762.1  25741   C   0:0:62:0:0:0    0:43:0:0:0:0     NA   intergenic_region C   T
NW_006532762.1  32304   T   0:60:0:0:0:0    0:0:49:0:0:0     NA   intergenic_region T   C 
NW_006532762.1  179065  G   0:0:0:45:0:0    59:0:0:0:0:0    DOCK4   intron_variant  G   A
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: yes, it's a text file but it is too large to do by hand.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a script-writing service, but we'll happily help you address issues you have with your own code.

Comment: some rows in columns 6 and 7 are empty but there should still be tab-delimited. I can try to fill it with NAs

Comment: @roaima Probably the column delimiter is a tab, but we can't see there are two tabs on those rows. The cells are empty. But if delimiter is tab, that would make the input already with 8 columns, first column empty.

Comment: Tell me you didn't do that by hand since it seems like the input file in this question is the output produced from your previous one (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/553248/133219) and that's obviously trivial to tweak to stick NA in the empty spots.

Comment: I didn't insert the NAs by hand, I figured out how to do that. I just don't know how to add the additional two columns with the appropriate letter from columns 4 and 5.

Comment: You don't need to populate NAs at all since your file is tab-separated so there's no ambiguity about where fields are vs separators and if you did then setting your FS to `[[:space:]]` when it's a tab-separated file wouldn't be ideal. If your fields are separated by tabs then set FS to `\t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it as follows using Perl and sed utilities:

```
perl -F'\t' -pale '$"="\t";
   /(?:^|:)(?=[1-9])/g, push(@F, qw[A T C G N del][+pos>>1]) for @F[3,4];
   $_="@F";
' file.tsv

NW_006532398.1 302035   C  0:0:32:0:0:0   42:0:0:0:0:0   KCND2 intergenic_region C  A
NW_006532398.1 302035   C  0:0:0:0:0:2 42:0:0:0:0:0   KCND2 intergenic_region del   A
NW_006532656.1 289636   C  0:0:28:0:0:0   0:28:0:0:0:0   CNTN1 intron_variant C  T
NW_006532762.1 6396  C  0:54:0:0:0:0   0:0:53:0:0:0   NA intergenic_region T  C
NW_006532762.1 25741 C  0:0:62:0:0:0   0:43:0:0:0:0   NA intergenic_region C  T
NW_006532762.1 32304 T  0:60:0:0:0:0   0:0:49:0:0:0   NA intergenic_region T  C
NW_006532762.1 179065   G  0:0:0:45:0:0   59:0:0:0:0:0   DOCK4 intron_variant G  A

sed -re '
   1{x;s/.*/A:T:C:G:N:del/;x;}
   s/\t/&\n/3;G;ba
   :b;s/\t/&\n/4;G
   :a;s/\n0:(.*)\n[^:]+:/0:\n\1\n/;ta
   s/\n//;s/\n([^:]+)/\t\1\n/;s/\n.*//;s/^//;tc
   :c;s/\t/&/8;t;bb
' file.tsv
```

**Explanations:**

- On the fourth `$F[3]` and fifth `$F[4]` fields of the current record`$_`(aka, line) we

  determine the position (within that field) of the first nonzero digit. By virtue of the fact

  that `0:` take up 2 locations we halve the found position to get the anonymous array `qw[A T C G N del]` index for that field.
- Now it's just a matter of just tacking the found A/T/C/G/N or del to the array `@F`.
- We then extrapolate the array `@F` using the `$"` (tab) and then print it.

**Assumptions:**

1. No leading TABs, which spoil the counting of the fields in the `@F` array.
2. The fourth and fifth fields are assumed to be `one-hot`, meaning, always, exactly one nonzero number is sure to be there.
3. The fourth and fifth fields do not have any nonzero number beginning with a 0.
4. The fourth and fifth fields do not have all 00 for a zero.
5. The fourth and fifth fields have exactly six numbers separated by single colons and no trailing/leading colon.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
    split("A:T:C:G:N:del",map,/:/)
}
{ print $0, vals2id($4), vals2id($5) }
function vals2id(vals,  arr, i, id) {
    split(vals,arr,/:/)
    for (i in arr) {
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            id = map[i]
        }
    }
    return id
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
NW_006532398.1  302035  C       0:0:32:0:0:0    42:0:0:0:0:0    KCND2   intergenic_region       C       A
NW_006532656.1  289636  C       0:0:28:0:0:0    0:28:0:0:0:0    CNTN1   intron_variant  C       T
NW_006532762.1  6396    C       0:54:0:0:0:0    0:0:53:0:0:0    NA      intergenic_region       T       C
NW_006532762.1  25741   C       0:0:62:0:0:0    0:43:0:0:0:0    NA      intergenic_region       C       T
NW_006532762.1  32304   T       0:60:0:0:0:0    0:0:49:0:0:0    NA      intergenic_region       T       C
NW_006532762.1  179065  G       0:0:0:45:0:0    59:0:0:0:0:0    DOCK4   intron_variant  G       A
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following sed script will do the things you want:

```sed
s/\t[1-9][0-9]*:0:0:0:0:[^\t]*\t/&A\t/g
s/\t0:[1-9][0-9]*:0:0:0:[^\t]*\t/&T\t/g
s/\t0:0:[1-9][0-9]*:0:0:[^\t]*\t/&C\t/g
s/\t0:0:0:[1-9][0-9]*:0:[^\t]*\t/&G\t/g
s/\t0:0:0:0:[1-9][0-9]*:[^\t]*\t/&N\t/g
s/\t0:0:0:0:0:[1-9][0-9]*\t/&del\t/g
s/^\t(([^\t]*\t){4})([^\t]*)\t([^\t]*)(\t[^\t]*)(\t.*)/\1\4\6\t\3\5/
```

Run with:

```sh
sed -rf script.sed file.tsv > output.tsv
```